# PHP - MYSQL Filter variable from while loop that contain any of specified words

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got a `while loop` that outputs user's comments. 
I need to filter the comments if it contains any of the word from `filter_table`

Query for the comment

```
$cm_qr = $db -> prepare ("SELECT comment FROM comment_tbl WHERE post_id = :pid");
$cm_qr -> bindParam (":pid", $pid);
$cm_qr -> execute();
    while($row = $cm_qr -> fetch()){
        $comment = $row_cm_qr['comment'];   


        }
```

Query for my filtered words

```
                $check_filter = $db -> query ("SELECT filter_word FROM filter_tbl");
                $check_filter -> execute();
                while($filter_row = $check_filter -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $fword = $filter_row['filter_word'];
                }
                    $fwords = array($fword);
```

Comment: Is there a question in there or is this an excuse to use profanity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are getting the list of filter words is wrong. You aren't making any array from them.
For this purpose you can use a dedicated fetch mode provided by PDO, [PDO::FETCH_COLUMN](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_COLUMN)

```
$fwords = $db->query("SELECT filter_word FROM filter_tbl")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

This will give you an array with words.

As of the filtering, just write a simple loop (inside your while loop) like this

```
foreach ($fwords as $word)
{
    if (strpos($comment, $word) !== false)
    {
        continue 2; //skip that comment from processing
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns an Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: It worked now! Thank you I was trying to crack this for almost 2 hours and I couldn't get it. Thank you! Thank You!